# About "the Sunstein of today"

Tags: definite-article

From [chronicle.com](http://chronicle.com/article/How-Intellectuals-Create-a/234984):

> While **the Sunstein of today** still believes that the individual’s preferences can be transformed, and that politics is the transformation of those preferences, the subject of those preferences and the instruments of their transformation have been recast.

Sunstein is a person, why is there a **the** before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author contrasts Cass Sunstein's  at two different stages of his intellectual development, and treats them rhetorically as two *different* 'Sunsteins': the Sunstein of the 80s and 90s and the Sunstein of today.